# How do I delete projects from GAE launcher

Tags: google-app-engine

Old ones show up as read because the source files are deleted. But they are still listed in the launcher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not an instinctive shortcut... but if you open the different menus, you can see that under `File`, there is a `Remove Project...` button.

The shortcut is ctrl+Del